# How do you change a photo of a location in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

If you're actually the owner of a location in Google Maps, how do you change the picture of it?

For an example of what I mean:

[image: google maps overlay with image]

If that was my location or business, how do I update or change the photo that appears in the information overlay?

Answer (score 2):

According to what I found on [Google Support](https://support.google.com/places/answer/176504), if you're the verified owner of a local business listing, all you can do is report inappropriate images. I don't see a way to add a new image, except to add it to your Google Places for business account.